# How can I run an XtraUserControl into a SplitContainerControl

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a SplitContainerControl in my form which is contains to panels (panel1 and panel2) the panel 1 contains a NavBarControl .
I created an XtraUserControl which contains some controls, and I want when I click in some Item in the NavBarControl to run this XtraUserControl  into panel2 of this SplitContainerControl but I dont know the method which allows me to do that !

this is the event which allows me to run some code when I click on some Item in the NavBarControl :

```
private void listeLivres_LinkPressed(object sender, DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarLinkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Some Code Here
        }
```

If there isn't a way to do that, Is there any other solution like some container which allows me to contain the XtraUserControl